# Python Pandas find statistical difference between 2 distributions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

i have 2 columns with similar data. I plot them to compare their distributions and i want to quantify their difference.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['cat','dog','bird','cat','dog','dog','dog'],
             'b':['cat','cat','cat','bird','dog','dog','dog']})
```

I then plot the 2 columns of my data frame to compare their distributions:

```
ax = df['a'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color='blue', width=.75, legend=True, alpha=0.8)
df['b'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', color='maroon', width=.5, alpha=1, legend=True)
```

[image]

How can i quantify the difference in the distributions statistically to say how similar they are?

would it be a simple t-test or something else?

Comment: You can compare their [statistical moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Your data seems to be binary/discrete, so Pearson's Chi-Squared test would be more appropriate to use here?

Comment: @Mika72 Pearson's is applicable when the number of expected and actual outcomes is over 5, for example. It cannot be used everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very common to use the [two-sided Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) for this.

In Python, you can do so with [`scipy.stats.ks_2samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html):

```
from scipy import stats

merged = pd.merge(
    df.a.value_counts().to_frame(),
    df.b.value_counts().to_frame(),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True)

stats.ks_2samp(merged.a, merged.b)
```

Broadly speaking, if the second value of the returned tuple is small (say less than 0.05), you should reject the hypothesis that the distributions are the same.

Comment: yes i was looking for the KS test! thanks for showing this intuitive example

Comment: Why do you merge? And why do you calculate value_counts? Shouldn't you pass the sequences of the individual values (not the frequencies) like `stats.ks_2samp(df.a, df.b)`?

Comment: @MoRe The `value_counts()` is required to convert the categorical variable into continuous for each column a and b because KS 2-sided can only be applied for continuous data additionally with an assumption that they (a and b) are independent.